# How to use index in computed observable [knockout.js]

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

Below is some example code. I need to use the items index in a computed variable, but I cant figure out how to do it without accessing the variable holding the view model app.

```
<template type="text/ko-template" id="rowTemplate">
    <li><span data-bind="text: number"></span> = <span data-bind="text: word"></span></li>
</template>

<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'rowTemplate', foreach: rowArray }"></ul>

<script>

    function RowModel(word) {
        var self = this;
        self.word = ko.observable(word);
        self.number = ko.computed({
            read: function(){
                return "#" + app.rowArray.indexOf(self); // This works, but is far from ideal.
            },
            deferEvaluation: true
        });

    };

    function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.rowArray = ko.observableArray([
            new RowModel('Zero'),
            new RowModel('One'),
            new RowModel('Two'),
        ]);
    };

    var app = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(app);

</script>
```

I've tried changing the line with the comment to many things, such as `$index`, `self.index()`, and all similar combos with `$parentContext`, etc.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25179606/3800244

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question as a simplification of my true 'problem', which may not have been the best idea. My intention was to access the context in the computed observable, thus my mention of `$parentContext`.

My research has lead to the following stack overflow question and answers, regarding the 'context': [How can I use knockout's $parent/$root pseudovariables from inside a .computed() observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8640748/3800244)

Knockout does provide [some functions](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html) for getting the context, but they do not work in this scenario (they are useful in event handlers only):

> ko.dataFor(element) - returns the data that was available for binding against the element
>   ko.contextFor(element) - returns the entire binding context that was available to the DOM element.

Thus it seems the best solution is very similar to my original question, but it explicitly stores the 'context' on the model object, to then be used in the computed observable (as discussed further in the aforementioned S.O. questions and answers)

```
function RowModel(word, context) {
    var self = this;
    self.word = ko.observable(word);
    self.context = context; // Save the 'context' to the object.
    self.number = ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            return "#" + self.context.rowArray.indexOf(self); // Do something with the 'context'.
        },
        deferEvaluation: true
    });
};

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.rowArray = ko.observableArray([
        new RowModel('Zero', self),
        new RowModel('One', self),
        new RowModel('Two', self),
    ]);
};
```

This sounds like a bit of a hassle, but it seems that knockout is basically doing the same 'under the hood' to [compute $index](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html):

> Unlike the other binding context properties, $index is an observable and is updated whenever the index of the item changes

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using computed you can go with `$index` in view which gives the current index of array.

**view:**

```
<template type="text/ko-template" id="rowTemplate">
    <li><span data-bind="text: '#'+($index()+1)"></span> = <span data-bind="text: word"></span></li>
</template>

<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'rowTemplate', foreach: rowArray }"></ul>
```

**viewModel:**

```
function RowModel(word) {
    var self = this;
    self.word = ko.observable(word);
};

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.rowArray = ko.observableArray([
        new RowModel('Zero'),
        new RowModel('One'),
        new RowModel('Two'),
    ]);
};

var app = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(app);
```

working sample **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26193/)**

Comment: Yes, that is definitely an option. I was going to mention in my question that I don't want to use this option though, as I want to use the computed variable in a number of locations, and I don't want to compute it more than once (ie I want to keep it DRY).

Comment: as far i see your way is the way to go (which is not advisable tough) . there are some ways which we can do but it achieves `dry` but  makes view `dirty`

Comment: something like this check here http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26195/ . before to 2.0 version this is the way index is found

Comment: Ah yep, that's not pretty, but it does get the job done. I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: @neRok  you find any alternative on this ? else try considering it to mark it as answer/upvote . cheers

Comment: I'll post an answer now. My goal was to access the index, and thus the context, within a computed observable. My answer will reflect this, however your answer isn't suitable as it does not actually work in a computed observable, but in the view.